# Query GeoServer connection with VPN

Tags: geoserver

We have a structured GIS from GeoServer version 2.15 (some layers loaded in shapefile format and others loaded from PostgreSQL). Therefore, we work with the GIS connected directly to the server and it works correctly, the problem arises when we connect from VPN, where the layers on the map are not shown (the layers loaded directly as shapefile and those that are in the base of PostgreSQL data). In this case, how can this situation be corrected and improved, from the point of view of the GeoServer configuration towards the VPN.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify whether your GeoServer is running on the client side or the server side of the VPN link.

Comment: GeoServer should not be able to tell if you are connecting through a VPN or not. Can you check the log file and add any relevant error messages to the question using the [edit] key